# Remove newline after incorrect field splitting in csv file

Tags: regex, csv, sed, split, newline

I use linux and I'm trying to use sed for this. I download a CSV from an institutional site providing some data to be analyzed. There are several thousand lines per CSV, and many columns per row (I haven't counted them, but I think the number is useless). The fields are separated by semicolons and quoted, so the format per line is:

```
"Field 1";"Field 2";"Field 3";  .... ;"Field X";
```

Each correct line ends with semicolon and '\n'. The problem is that, from time to time, there's some field that incorrectly has a newline, and the solution is to delete the newline character, so the two lines go back to be together into only one. Example of an incorrect line:

```
"Field 1";"Field 2";"Fi
eld 3";"Field X";
```

I've found that there can be a \n right after the opening quote or somewhere in the between the quotes.

I've found a way to manage this last case, where the newline is right after the quote:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/";"\n/";"/g' file.csv
```

but not for "any number of alphabet characters after the quote not ending in semicolon". I have a pattern file (to be used with -f) with these lines:

```
:a;N;$!ba;s/";"\n/";"/g
:a;N;$!ba;s/\([A-z]\)\n/\1/g
:a;N;$!ba;s/\([:alpha:]\)\n/\1/g
```

The first line of the pattern file works, but I've tried combinations of the second and third and I always get an empty file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If current line doesn't end with a semicolon, read and append next line to pattern space and remove line break.

```
sed '/[^;]$/{N;s/\n//}' file
```

Comment: Perhaps the newly appended line might also match the first condition, in which case a loop would be needed i.e. `sed ':a;/[^;]$/{N;s/\n//;ba}' file`